# using string in one way selection (if statement)

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I want to know how to use the string s1 in order to print success when StdMark>50. I need to do that in one-way selection, in other words without using else statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int StdMark;
    string s1;
    s1="succuss";
    cout <<"Enter The grade:"<<endl;
    cin >>StdMark;
    if(StdMark<50)
    {
        cout<<"fail";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the "else" keyword

Comment: No, i want to do it without using "else".

Comment: You can use ternary operator

Comment: I know it's easier to use ternary operator and "else", but I don't want to use them in my code.

Comment: @Mada, but… why? Okay, if you seriously want that, you may exit from the function under the first «if», and place the alternative after the «if» block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int StdMark;
    string s1;
    s1="succuss";
    cout <<"Enter The grade:"<<endl;
    cin >>StdMark; 
    if (StdMark<50)
    {
        s1="fail";
    }
    cout<<s1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an `if`/`else`, there are a couple of alternatives:

1. Use the `?:` ternary operator:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       int StdMark;
       cout << "Enter The grade:" << endl;
       cin >> StdMark;
       cout  << (StdMark < 50) ? "fail" : "success";
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. declare a 2-element array of strings containing `"success"` and `"fail"` in it, and then use the output of the `<` operator as an index into that array:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       const char* str[2] = {"success", "fail"};
       int StdMark;
       cout << "Enter The grade:" << endl;
       cin >> StdMark;
       cout  << str[StdMark < 50];
       return 0;
   }
   ```